# GKE Internal Load Balancer does not distribute load between gRPC servers

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, load-balancing, grpc, kubernetes-ingress

I have an API that recently started receiving more traffic, about 1.5x. That also lead to a doubling in the latency:

[image: latency]

This surprised me since I had setup autoscaling of both nodes and pods as well as GKE internal loadbalancing.

My external API passes the request to an internal server which uses a lot of CPU. And looking at my VM instances it seems like all of the traffic got sent to one of my two VM instances (a.k.a. Kubernetes nodes):

[image: CPU utilization per node]

With loadbalancing I would have expected the CPU usage to be more evenly divided between the nodes.

Looking at my deployment there is one pod on the first node:

[image: First pod on first node]

And two pods on the second node:

[image]

[image]

My service config:

```
$ kubectl describe service model-service
Name:                     model-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=model-server
Annotations:              networking.gke.io/load-balancer-type: Internal
Selector:                 app=model-server
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.3.249.180
IPs:                      10.3.249.180
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.128.0.18
Port:                     rest-api  8501/TCP
TargetPort:               8501/TCP
NodePort:                 rest-api  30406/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.0.145:8501,10.0.0.152:8501,10.0.1.135:8501
Port:                     grpc-api  8500/TCP
TargetPort:               8500/TCP
NodePort:                 grpc-api  31336/TCP
Endpoints:                10.0.0.145:8500,10.0.0.152:8500,10.0.1.135:8500
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason               Age                  From                Message
  ----    ------               ----                 ----                -------
  Normal  UpdatedLoadBalancer  6m30s (x2 over 28m)  service-controller  Updated load balancer with new hosts
```

The fact that Kubernetes started a new pod seems like a clue that Kubernetes autoscaling is working. But the pods on the second VM do not receive any traffic. How can I make GKE balance the load more evenly?

### Update Nov 2:

Goli's answer leads me to think that it has something to do with the setup of the model service. The service exposes both a REST API and a GRPC API but the GRPC API is the one that receives traffic.

There is a corresponding forwarding rule for my service:

```
$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules list --filter="loadBalancingScheme=INTERNAL"
NAME                              REGION       IP_ADDRESS   IP_PROTOCOL  TARGET
aab8065908ed4474fb1212c7bd01d1c1  us-central1  10.128.0.18  TCP          us-central1/backendServices/aab8065908ed4474fb1212c7bd01d1c1
```

Which points to a backend service:

```
$ gcloud compute backend-services describe aab8065908ed4474fb1212c7bd01d1c1
backends:
- balancingMode: CONNECTION
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/questions-279902/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroups/k8s-ig--42ce3e0a56e1558c
connectionDraining:
  drainingTimeoutSec: 0
creationTimestamp: '2021-02-21T20:45:33.505-08:00'
description: '{"kubernetes.io/service-name":"default/model-service"}'
fingerprint: lA2-fz1kYug=
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/questions-279902/global/healthChecks/k8s-42ce3e0a56e1558c-node
id: '2651722917806508034'
kind: compute#backendService
loadBalancingScheme: INTERNAL
name: aab8065908ed4474fb1212c7bd01d1c1
protocol: TCP
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/questions-279902/regions/us-central1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/questions-279902/regions/us-central1/backendServices/aab8065908ed4474fb1212c7bd01d1c1
sessionAffinity: NONE
timeoutSec: 30
```

Which has a health check:

```
$ gcloud compute health-checks describe k8s-42ce3e0a56e1558c-node                                          
checkIntervalSec: 8
creationTimestamp: '2021-02-21T20:45:18.913-08:00'
description: ''
healthyThreshold: 1
httpHealthCheck:
  host: ''
  port: 10256
  proxyHeader: NONE
  requestPath: /healthz
id: '7949377052344223793'
kind: compute#healthCheck
logConfig:
  enable: true
name: k8s-42ce3e0a56e1558c-node
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/questions-279902/global/healthChecks/k8s-42ce3e0a56e1558c-node
timeoutSec: 1
type: HTTP
unhealthyThreshold: 3
```

List of my pods:

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
api-server-deployment-6747f9c484-6srjb     2/2     Running   3          3d22h
label-server-deployment-6f8494cb6f-79g9w   2/2     Running   4          38d
model-server-deployment-55c947cf5f-nvcpw   0/1     Evicted   0          22d
model-server-deployment-55c947cf5f-q8tl7   0/1     Evicted   0          18d
model-server-deployment-766946bc4f-8q298   1/1     Running   0          4d5h
model-server-deployment-766946bc4f-hvwc9   0/1     Evicted   0          6d15h
model-server-deployment-766946bc4f-k4ktk   1/1     Running   0          7h3m
model-server-deployment-766946bc4f-kk7hs   1/1     Running   0          9h
model-server-deployment-766946bc4f-tw2wn   0/1     Evicted   0          7d15h
model-server-deployment-7f579d459d-52j5f   0/1     Evicted   0          35d
model-server-deployment-7f579d459d-bpk77   0/1     Evicted   0          29d
model-server-deployment-7f579d459d-cs8rg   0/1     Evicted   0          37d
```

How do I A) confirm that this health check is in fact showing 2/3 backends as unhealthy? And B) configure the health check to send traffic to all of my backends?

### Update Nov 5:

After finding that several pods had gotten evicted in the past because of too little RAM, I migrated the pods to a new nodepool. The old nodepool VMs had 4 CPU and 4GB memory, the new ones have 2 CPU and 8GB memory. That seems to have resolved the eviction/memory issues, but the loadbalancer still only sends traffic to one pod at a time.

Pod 1 on node 1:

[image: Pod 1 on node 1]

Pod 2 on node 2:

[image]

It seems like the loadbalancer is not splitting the traffic at all but just randomly picking one of the GRPC modelservers and sending 100% of traffic there. Is there some configuration that I missed which caused this behavior? Is this related to me using GRPC?

Comment: The healthcheck output you posted is for the node and not the pod. Can you post a `kubectl get pods .. `?

Comment: @LukasEichler thank you, I added the output from `kubectl get pods` as well.

Comment: @Johan Wikstrom I have updated my answer with some findings. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know the answer from what you've posted, but I assume you are using a Service of type LoadBalancer and not using Ingress?

Comment: Correct, I am using a Loadbalancer. See the service YAML I put in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the answer is that you **cannot loadbalance gRPC requests using a GKE loadbalancer**.

A GKE loadbalancer (as well as Kubernetes' default loadbalancer) picks a new backend every time a new TCP connection is formed. For regular HTTP 1.1 requests each request gets a new TCP connection and the loadbalancer works fine. For gRPC (which is based on HTTP 2), the TCP connection is only setup once and all requests are multiplexed on the same connection.

More details in this [blog post](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/11/07/grpc-load-balancing-on-kubernetes-without-tears/).

To enable gRPC loadbalancing I had to:

1. Install Linkerd

```
curl -fsL https://run.linkerd.io/install | sh
linkerd install | kubectl apply -f -
```

2. Inject the Linkerd proxy in **both** the receiving and sending pods:

[image]

```
kubectl apply -f api_server_deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f model_server_deployment.yaml
```

3. After realizing that Linkerd would not work together with the GKE loadbalancer, I exposed the receiving deployment as a ClusterIP service instead.

```
kubectl expose deployment/model-server-deployment
```

4. Pointed the gRPC client to the ClusterIP service IP address I just created, and redeployed the client.
   [image]

```
kubectl apply -f api_server_deployment.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud provides health checks to determine if backends respond to traffic.Health checks connect to backends on a configurable, periodic basis. Each connection attempt is called a probe. Google Cloud records the success or failure of each probe.

Based on a configurable number of sequential successful or failed probes, an overall health state is computed for each backend. Backends that respond successfully for the configured number of times are considered healthy.

Backends that fail to respond successfully for a separately configurable number of times are unhealthy.

**The overall health state of each backend determines eligibility to receive new requests or connections**.So one of the chances of instance not getting requests can be that your instance is unhealthy. Refer to this documentation for [creating health checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-checks) .

You can configure the criteria that define a successful probe. This is discussed in detail in the section [How health checks work](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#method).

**Edit1:**

The Pod is evicted from the node due to lack of resources, or the node fails. If a node fails, Pods on the node are automatically scheduled for deletion.

So to know the exact reason for pods getting evicted Run
`kubectl describe pod <pod name>` and look for the node name of this pod. Followed by `kubectl describe node <node-name>` that will show what type of resource cap the node is hitting under **Conditions: section.**

From my experience this happens when the host node runs out of disk space.
Also after starting the pod you should run `kubectl logs <pod-name> -f` and see the logs for more detailed information.

Refer this documentation for more information on [eviction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/node-pressure-eviction/#eviction-thresholds).

Comment: Thank you for your help so far @Goli . I really appreciate it. The pods were evicted because their nodes ran out of memory so I migrated the pods to VMs with more memory. Sadly the same issue persisted, the loadbalancer seems to randomly pick a pod and send all the traffic there. I added two more graphs to the original question showing this phenomenon. Are the routing decisions of the loadbalancer logged anywhere? If so, perhaps the logs could provide a clue as to what went wrong.